# Laravel eloquent Eager Loading with conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to know how to load the **sender** only when **inbox.sender_id !=  Auth::user()->id**
and the same for the **receiver** load it when only **inbox.receiver_id !=  Auth::user()->id**

code :

```
  $inboxs = Inbox::select("id", "sender_id", "receiver_id")
            ->where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->with('sender')
            ->with('receiver')
            ->OrderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
```

I have these **relations** in the Inbox Model :

```
public function sender(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id');
}

public function receiver(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'receiver_id');
}
```

Migration File :

```
Schema::create('inboxes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('sender_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->foreignId('receiver_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called [Constraining Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.